# How to get the power consumed by memory on IOS devices?

Tags: ios

I'd like to know the power related to transferring data from off-chip memory (DRAM) to on-chip memory (SRAM) or cache. I'd also like to know the power related to L1/L2/L3 cache. Is it possible to get data like that? If so, how to get that?

Even some proxy metrics may be good, such as cache miss rate, amount of data transferred, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get data like that? If so, how to get that?

Not directly. I think your best bet would be to write an app that intentionally reads lots of data randomly from a wide range of memory locations, basically creating as many cache misses as possible. You could analyze the app using the Energy Log tool in Instruments, or just run the app for as long as possible on a single memory charge. Then change the app's behavior so that the same data is read from sequential locations, thus maximizing cache hits, and measure battery usage the same way as before.

You're not going to get data about the actual amount of power used this way (it's a good bet that the screen, radios, and processor use far more energy than the memory does) but you might get a better idea of the relative power savings provided by the cache. You might want to measure time used to read a constant amount of data this way, too -- you should see a significant speed increase with the cache.